# JSDoc nested function dosen't make doc

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, jsdoc

JSDoc nested function dosen't make doc.
I saw https://jsdoc.app/tags-mixin.html, It is dose not works for me.
I wont make doc in my doc right this.

How to works for me decorater Mixin?
I'll appreciate your answer.

[image]

this is my code.

```js
/**
 * @class angular_service.PrivilegeService
 * @memberOf angular_service
 * @name PrivilegeService
 * @description none
 */
app.service("PrivilegeService", [
  "$parse",
  "Auth",
  "Const",
  "$location",
  "$timeout",
  function($parse, Auth, Const, $location, $timeout) {
    var idx,
      loginUserInfo,
      privilege,
      permissionType = Const.PERMISSION_TYPE;

    /**
     * @mixin
     */
    var privilegeService = {
      /**
       * @param {string}  moduleName
       * @description module import
       */
      getModuleId: function(moduleName) {
        var moduleId = "";
        for (var key in Const.PERMISSION_MODULE_ID) {
          if (Const.PERMISSION_MODULE_ID.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (key == moduleName) {
              moduleId = Const.PERMISSION_MODULE_ID[key];
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return moduleId;
      },
      /**
       * @param {string}  moduleId
       * @description find out id
       */
      getModuleNameByModuleId: function(moduleId) {
        var moduleName = "";
        for (var key in Const.PERMISSION_MODULE_ID) {
          if (Const.PERMISSION_MODULE_ID.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (Const.PERMISSION_MODULE_ID[key] == moduleId) {
              moduleName = key;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return moduleName;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following is one approach for the documentation as required

```
/**
 * @class angular_service.PrivilegeService
 * @memberOf angular_service
 * @name PrivilegeService
 * @description none
 */
app.service("PrivilegeService", [
  "$parse",
  "Auth",
  "Const",
  "$location",
  "$timeout",
  function($parse, Auth, Const, $location, $timeout) {
    var idx,
      loginUserInfo,
      privilege,
      permissionType = Const.PERMISSION_TYPE;
 /**
 * @function privilegeService
 * @memberof angular_service.PrivilegeService
 * @mixin
 */
    var privilegeService = {
       /**
         * @function getModuleId
         * @memberof angular_service.PrivilegeService.privilegeService
         * @param {string}  moduleName
         * @description module import
         */
        getModuleId: function(moduleName) {
          var moduleId = "";
          for (var key in Const.PERMISSION_MODULE_ID) {
            if (Const.PERMISSION_MODULE_ID.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              if (key == moduleName) {
                moduleId = Const.PERMISSION_MODULE_ID[key];
                break;
              }
            }
          }
          return moduleId;
        },
        /**
         * @function getModuleNameByModuleId
         * @memberof angular_service.PrivilegeService.privilegeService
         * @param {string}  moduleId
         * @description find out id
         */
        getModuleNameByModuleId: function(moduleId) {
          var moduleName = "";
          for (var key in Const.PERMISSION_MODULE_ID) {
            if (Const.PERMISSION_MODULE_ID.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              if (Const.PERMISSION_MODULE_ID[key] == moduleId) {
                moduleName = key;
                break;
              }
            }
          }
          return moduleName;
        }
    }
});
```